# How to access request parameters in a view and iterate over hash in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to access the requests parameters submitted over the form in a view and iterate over the hash values.

My definition in a view:

```
def show
  @final =final_params
end
```

My Request parameters:

```
def final_params
  params.permit(:Name, :Address, :MobileNumber, :"City")
end
```

My view:

```
<%= @final.each { |key, value| puts "#{key} #{value}" } %>
```

In my Show view it gives an empty array:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywe0J.png)

Using console I see the data in forms data section:

```
.utf8: ✓
authenticity_token: Lxkt/WUyAqFvlLXcP7YsQY3PjhQ9yJFosByJwAfYRyoZseC4gaZj4J8cC4EJs/LLGBIMypbggpajmtCH3um2dA==
final[Name]: Test
final[Address]: Hyd
final[MobileNumber]: 8456213254
final[City]: Del
commit: Submit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of `puts` in your view, it's not needed.

```
<% @final.keys.each do |key| %>
  key: <%= key %> <br/>
  value: <%= @final[key] %>
<% end %>
```

Or you can probably just do

```
<%= @final.inspect %>
```

If that's still empty then no params are being passed to your controller action.
To sure add this in your controller and look at the logs:

```
def show
  @final = final_params
  puts "Final Params are set to: #{@final.inspect}" # or logger debug if puts doesn't output anything to your log
  logger.debug  "Final Params are set to: #{@final.inspect}"
  @final 
end
```

Comment: still i don't see any data.

Comment: @mallelaprakash You **probably** need to `params.permit(:name, :address, :mobile_number, :city)` - but this is only a best guess, as I haven't seen your `params`! Try printing them from inside the controller action, to see the true values.